# Efficient way to match regex between delimiters

Tags: regex, match

I have a string and want to match the substring between the two first delimiters with a regular expression.

For example a string `foo"text"bar anotherfoo"anothertext"anotherbar` with delimiter `"` should yield `text`.

I found the following possible solutions:

- Non-greedy matching `"(.*?)"`
- Non-greedy matching with Lookahead and Lookbehind assertions `(?<=")(.*?)(?=")`
- Negated character classes `"([^"]*)"`

Which one is the most efficient way of doing this? Or am I missing cases where these solutions behave differently (assuming the new line modifier is set so that a dot matches a new line)?

Comment: JS, PHP, .NET or ..?

Comment: @choz I was using python while testing this.

Comment: The second one doesn't work on JS. And the last one is of course better than the first one if you compare them since they're two different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the delimiters are single characters, and the matched substring should not contain them, the **negated character class** solution (`"([^"]*)"`) is the most efficient.

If you want to match only once, you do not even need the closing `"`: just use `"([^"]*)`.

The lazy dot matching (`"(.*?)"`) technique might cause performance issues when there is no ending delimiter and the text is rather large after the initial delimiter.

Lookarounds almost always involve additional overhead of checking for some subpatterns at each tested position. Since the delimiters here are single characters, the lookbehind/lookahead here are not efficient. You only want to use this solution if *there is no way to access capturing groups*. In Python, capturing works well, so no need using this solution.